# Php error in connecting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to access mysql database through php. The problem is that every time I load the page, there is nothing on the screen. And when I tried to add the code `ini_set('display_errors',1);`, an error occurred which is `fatal ERROR: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/loginVerification.php`

The code that I had used was

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);

session_start();

$username = "formtemplate";

$password = "admin123";

$hostname = "localhost";

$db = "forms";

$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $db)or die ( mysqli_error($dbhandle) );
```

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: mysqli is not configured/installed to work with PHP.

Comment: Please install MySQLi extension if you are system owner or check with your system admin.

Comment: And try switching to PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

I think mysqli would work fine. What I did is just to reinstall my php5 and after that it had work perfectly. Thank You for your answers.